# Display same models two times in django admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model named Packages. In django admin the list of packages will be listed when I click on Package link which is shown below

[image]

I want the package list to be displayed two times in this same page so that i can apply different ordering filters to two packages. How to modify admin.py to obtain this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I'd like to be proven wrong though. A custom view with some third party app that renders a table would most likely work though.

Answer (score 0):

Look into proxy models.  They allow you to register a given model multiple times.